# What files should I copy from Windows into Wine?

Tags: linux, windows, libraries, wine

As far as I understand Wine runtime does better if some libraries are copied from MS Windows, but some Windows system libraries really are not to be used with Wine (some can even make it stop working, and many are simply useless).

So what files make sense and are safe to copy from MS Windows into Wine system?

I own a legal Windows XP copy (but prefer to use GNU/Linux) and run Wine 1.3.8 on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: For what purpose?  In other words, what are you trying to run in Wine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks) to install the files instead, some files needs specific changes to wine registery which `winetricks` handle.